# How to add text under the image to the right in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and I want the text to be under the image to the right.

I have tried using `float: right;` but then the text is beside the image to the right.

[image: example of what I wanted]

```css
.image-container {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
}

.image {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: right;
}

.text {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container">
    <img src="Safwon.png" alt="Picture of the author" width="150" height="200" class="image" />
    <div class="text">This is me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi :) you need to provide your code when posting questions or else ppl can't SEE where you are going wrong.

Comment: See [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .container{
            display: flex;
            gap: 10px;
        }
        p{
            align-self: flex-end;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://www.ayvalikpetshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/kedi-bakimi.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, rem.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: bro not working

Comment: Always explain your answers. Never dump a block of code and expect everyone to figure it out.

Comment: you should share to your codes to we find where is the problem and Can you give more detail about what to actually you want ?

Comment: plz see the picture you can find what i want

Comment: give your .container float:left instead of img and remove float from img. if you wanna put img too. you should put clear:both for text

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `image-container` to your [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) as an [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) but in your CSS, you wrote it as a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) therefore your code didn't work. Change `.image-container` to `#image-container`.

```css
#image-container {
  float: right;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400.png" alt="Picture of the author" width="150" height="200" class="image">
  <div class="text">This is me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh ok but the text isnt aligned correctly underr the image

Comment: @SafwonBinFaisal [As far as I see, it's.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tICe.png) Where do you want it? Center or to the left?

Comment: i want the image to the right also the text but text should be the caption of the image(This is my 1st time )

Comment: @SafwonBinFaisal See my new updates, that's what you want?

Comment: @SafwonBinFaisal It worked or not?

Comment: Hey tnx for helping me now it is correct . It is what I wanted  . I was stuck at that and  many many thanks

Comment: @SafwonBinFaisal Therefore please upvote my answer (click that up arrow) and click the grey checkmark on my answer so I gain some reputation (and mark this question as solved) to be able to help more people. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the rule `clear: right;` to your other `.text` div rules

Comment: but the text isnt aligned correctly under the image . It is aligned to right yes but not straight under the image

Comment: @SafwonBinFaisal It's difficult to tell from your image where you wanted the text aligned. Also, you have a CSS rule for `.image-container` but there's no element with that class. There's one with that ID though. So did you mean `#image-container`?

Comment: yep that was my mistake